# Jpa/hibernate problem while merge entity after remove related entity from it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I have two classes A and B that have many to many relationship. When i delete one item from list of B in class A and trying to merge this is doesn't work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = getAByIdFromRepository(2);
        B b = a.getB().stream().filter(i -> i.getId() == 1).findFirst().orElse(null);
        a.remove(b);
        repositoryMerge(a);
    }

    public static A getAByIdFromRepository(int id) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        A a = em.find(A.class, id);
        em.close();
        factory.close();
        return a;
    }

    public static void repositoryMerge(A a) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(a);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    protected int id;
    @Column(name = "a_name")
    protected String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<B> b;

   //getters setters etc.

    public void remove(B b) {
        this.getB().remove(b);
        b.getA().remove(this);
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    protected int id;
    @Column(name = "b_name")
    protected String name;
    @JoinTable(
            name = "b_a",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"))
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<A> a;

  //getters setters etc.


}
```

For example i have related table in database b_a that connects these entities and there is no deletion from this table after merge. When i fetch instance of A then close entity manager, delete from list of this instance some B elements, open entity manager again and merge this is doesn't work.

Comment: hello! what happens if instead of repositoryMerge(a); you have repositoryMerge(a, b); and in a single transaction you save both a and b? in your example changes to b are never persisted; b.a could still contain the A b was removed from

Comment: Why do i need to save b? i want a separate repository for a and b. I know that my example works while i doing all with one opened entity manager. Open entity manager, fetch a, find b with particular id, remove it from a with remove(b) method and merge. Only after this close entity manager and all is works, when i trying to do same with detached entity this doesn't work. I don't get this hibernate behavior. Strangely when update not collection fields, name, for example this works with detached entity.